# Setting title to FPS libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I have seen it done in libgdx projects before so I know it is possible. I would like to display the FPS of the game as the title of the application. I just can't seem to figure out how to do this as it seems the title of my game is always static. It always says 0. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you can add in your render/controller method something like this:

Gdx.graphics.setTitle("your fps");

Comment: I guess you could specify "your fps", so that it actually shows the fps.

Comment: question was about "how to show fps", not "how to calculate". however, you can use build-in function Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()

Comment: I know (I didn't ask the question), but your answer does not solve the problem. Since as you said libgdx provides a method for if you could just add it there, otherwise only another static string will be set as the title.

Comment: I will set this as correct but everyone please listen. In order to accomplish what I want you do this but instead of the string in the parameter, put Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond() + ""

Comment: @Temo It was probably assumed you would know to convert from `int` to `String`, which is why nzaroma just posted a general String for his argument. The "more correct" way of doing it is to do `String.valueof(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond())`, but the result is basically the same as what you did.

Answer (score 4):

use bitmapfont to display your FPS

```
BitmapFont font;


@Override
public void create() {
    font = new BitmapFont();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    //OpenGL settings
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    Gdx.graphics.setTitle(""+Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());
    batch.end();
}
```

if any trouble leave a comment ! enjoy :)

**Updated**